# bootstrap:themed error - not generating the proper views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Rails: 3.2.6
twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.3, 2.1.0)

I did the following:

```
rails generate bootstrap:install static -s
```

I then generated the scaffolding for certification as follows:

```
rails generate scaffold certification id:integer user_id:integer name:string description:string location:string status:string --skip-stylesheets -s
```

Then I tried to generate the twitter bootstrap views as follows:

```
rails generate bootstrap:themed certifications -f -s
```

Which gave me the following error:

```
undefined method `fields' for #<Class:0x007fe5e7282060>
```

and no changes were made to the certifications views. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you creating an id for? The id is usually generated. What does the `-f` and `-s` command do?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, because I was working with a mix of mongoid and active records. I guess somehow there were conflicts while using the generator and it couldn't find the fields method anymore.

The solution for me was a reinstall twitter-bootstrap-rails gem with the following:

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", :git => 'https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
```

Also, do not forget to run

```
rake db:migrate
```

after your

```
rails generate scaffold ...
```

For those working with mongoid, additional tip: everytime I have to generate a scaffold for an active record, I comment:

```
#gem "mongoid", "~> 3.0"
#gem "composite_primary_keys"
```

Then, generate, then uncomment